# Jenkins - Execute sh commands with certain special characters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to use a Jenkins sh command that looks like this:

```
find ./somedir -type f -name .pdf -exec mv {} ./someotherdir/scan.pdf \;
```

(This works on regular bash shell)

But in Jenkins when I use:

```
sh 'find ./somedir -type f -name .pdf -exec mv {} ./someotherdir/scan.pdf \\;'
```

It interprets it to:

```
find ./somedir -type f -name .pdf -exec mv '{}' ./someotherdir/scan.pdf ';'
```

I've tried a lot of different things to escape this properly and I just can't figure it out...

The examples online mentioned elsewhere do not seem to work or I do not understand them.

Comment: Similar: https://superuser.com/questions/1326117/groovy-syntax-not-working-with-backslashes

Comment: no need to escape \  when use single quote wrap the bash cmd, so change  to \;

Comment: @yong Not true. This is a Groovy string, which requires escaping of the backslash (see https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_escaping_special_characters).

Comment: Is this re-interpretation really causing a problem? The `find` command still sees exactly the same arguments and can't tell the difference.

Comment: @Michael Kemmerzell - Nice article thank you.  The + at the end is helpful... but still can't get rid of the '{}' problem.  Every time I try to do a shell command it wraps with that.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this type of approach worked for me with sh in Jenkins.  As a user mentions above sometimes the extra encoding it does doesn't hurt.  I'll share the final command I did get working:

sh 'find ./temptest -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec mv {} ./temptest/scan.pdf ";"'

Notice that I have wildcard in "" and ; in ""

Hope this helps someone else!